# Unescape JSON from terraform provider

Tags: json, go, terraform

I am developing a custom terraform provider in Go.
I have a JSON parameter like this:

```
local_context_data = jsonencode({"hello"="world"})
```

When I check what is sent to the API with TCPdump I can see that the JSON is escaping like this:

```json
{\"hello\":\"world\"}.
```

But it generates an error because the API is waiting for real JSON without escape.
Do we have a function in Go to unescape this?
Or better: do we have a function in the terraform SDK?

Comment: Even if you unescape it, its still not valid json right? because of the = in the middle.

Comment: I made a mistake in my previous post. I just check now and it's not a "=" but ":". I updated my post.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you saw and where. In any case, double encoding/decoding is an issue which can be found and fixed. Extract a [mcve] for a start.

Answer (score 0):

if your API expects json, what you want is probably

```
local_context_data = {"hello"="world"}
```

You only need `jsonencode` if you want to send a json string within the json.

Comment: Perhaps it's true but I don't know what kind of type I should use for JSON in provider. There is no TypeJSON in https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/blob/8b29ee8423d640f0d2ff38b91851991197b6fe4d/helper/schema/schema.go#L44 ?

Comment: Is that related to this problem? Is that why you tried to jsonencode so its a string?

Comment: For the moment it's a TypeString in the provider so I used jsonencode in terraform. If I want to test with JSON directly in terraform I need to find something else than TypeString to put in the provider code.

Comment: That makes sense. And that means you are expecting a string. So it makes sense that those characters are escaped. Don't try to unescape them because if you did the whole json is not valid. you say "it generates an error", please post what error this is if you still need help with this.